# MySQL select a value from a table and sum values on another table based on the value from the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, subquery

I have two tables, users and sales. I want to be able to get the sum of all profits made by each user.

```
Users
_ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|id                  |
|first_name          |
|second_name         |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

```
Sales
_ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|id                  |
|user                |
|profit              |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
    (select sum(s.profit) from sales s where s.user = u.id) as total_sales
from users u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    u.second_name,
    u.first_name,
    SUM(s.profit)
FROM
    sales AS s
  JOIN
    users AS u ON u.id = s.user
GROUP BY
    u.id
```